# Distributed array in MPI for parallel numerics

Tags: memory-management, parallel-processing, mpi, distributed-computing

in many distributed computing applications, you maintain a distributed array of objects. Each process manages a set of objects that it may read and write exclusively and furthermore a set of objects that may only read (the content of which is authored by and frequently recerived from other processes).

This is very basic and is likely to have been done a zillion times until times until now - for example, with MPI. Hence I suppose there is something like an open source extension for MPI, which provides the basic capabilities of a distributed array for computing.

Ideally, it would be written in C(++) and mimic the official MPI standard interface style. Does anybody know anything like that? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

From what I gather from your question, you're looking for a mechanism for allowing a global view (read-only) of the problem space, but each process has ownership (read-write) of a segment of the data.

MPI is simply an API specification for inter-process communication for parallel applications and any implementation of it will work at a level lower than what you are looking for.

It is quite common in HPC applications to perform data decomposition in a way that you mentioned, with MPI used to synchronise shared data to other processes. However each application have different sharing patterns and requirements (some may wish to only exchange halo regions with neighbouring nodes, and perhaps using non-blocking calls to overlap communication other computation) so as to improve performance by making use of knowledge of the problem domain.

The thing is, using MPI to sync data across processes is simple but implementing a layer above it to handle general purpose distribute array synchronisation that is *easy to use* yet *flexible enough to handle different use cases* can be rather trickly.

Apologies for taking so long to get to the point, but **to answer your question**, AFAIK there isn't be an extension to MPI or a library that can efficiently handle all use cases while still being easier to use than simply using MPI. However, it is possible to to work above the level of MPI which maintaining distributed data. For example:

- Use the [PGAS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partitioned_global_address_space) model to work with your data. You can then use libraries such as [Global Arrays](http://hpc.pnl.gov/globalarrays/) (interfaces for C, C++, Fortran, Python) or languages that support PGAS such as [UPC](http://upc.gwu.edu/) or [Co-Array Fortran](http://caf.rice.edu/) (soon to be included into the Fortran standards). There are also languages designed specifically for this form of parallelism, i,e. [Fortress](https://java.net/projects/projectfortress/pages/Home), [Chapel](http://chapel.cray.com/), [X10](http://x10-lang.org/)
- Roll your own. For example, I've worked on a library that uses MPI to do all the dirty work but hides the complexity by providing creating custom data types for the application domain, and exposing APIs such as:

  - `X_Create(MODE, t_X)` : instantiate the array, called by all processes  with the `MODE` indicating if the current process will require READ-WRITE or READ-ONLY access
  - `X_Sync_start(t_X)` : non-blocking call to initiate synchronisation in the background.
  - `X_Sync_complete(t_X)` : data is required. Block if synchronisation has not completed.
  - ... and other calls to delete data as well as perform domain specific tasks that may require MPI calls.

To be honest, in most cases it is often simpler to stick with basic MPI or OpenMP, or if one exists, using a parallel solver written for the application domain. This of course depends on your requirements.

Answer (score 1):

For dense arrays, see Global Arrays and Elemental (Google will find them for you).

For sparse arrays, see PETSc.

I know this is a really short answer, but there is too much documentation of these elsewhere to bother repeating it.